# Workaround for param in Open BlueDragon

Tags: coldfusion, openbd

Open BlueDragon 2.0.2, does not support:

`param rc.nodeid    = "";`

In particular the param part does not work

What is a good workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not familiar with BD, each of these options should work:

Ternary operator:

```
rc.nodeid = structKeyExists( rc, "nodeid" ) ? rc.nodeid : "";
```

Normal if/else statement:

```
if( !structKeyExists( rc, "nodeid" ) ) {
    rc.nodeid = "";
}
```

Personally, I prefer the ternary operator because it's almost as concise as `param`, but you will be sacrificing some readability for those who are unfamiliar with it.

**EDIT**: I went and had a look at BD's [documentation](http://openbd.org/manual/?/cfscript#param). It looks like BD requires the "name" attribute, so you should be able to do this:

```
param name="rc.nodeid" default="";
```